# how to set logic the right way to use post variables

Tags: php, html, forms, logic

hello i have problem with the following code that is on the head of every page:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['a'])){
    ...create the session from some variables...
$_SESSION['a'] = $var;
$var = $_SESSION['a'];
}else{
    $var = $_SESSION['a'];
    $what = "some text";

    if (isset($_POST['one']) ){
        $var = "new input";
            $_SESSION['a'] = $var;
        echo "one was posted";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['two']) ){
            $var = "new input";
            $_SESSION['a'] = $var;
        echo "two was posted";
    }   
}
```

the form to post is placed in the footer:

```
<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">      
    <input type="submit" id="one" name="one"/><div>set one</div>
</form>
<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">  
    <input type="submit" id="two" name="two"/><div>set two</div>
</form>
```

something seems to be wrong in the logic behind the code above. when calling the page, and sending post issue, it will not echo and not change the session to the new value.

so if there is someone who could help me out i really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

UPDATE:

okay, the code works completely up to the "else" part:

```
else{
    $var = $_SESSION['a'];

    if (isset($_POST["one"]) ){
        echo "post one was send";
    }
    if (isset($_POST["two"]) ){
        echo "post en was send";
    }

echo "session already exists.";
}
```

this part only shows the echo: session already exists. the whole post phrase does not work.
the footer will be embedded depending from some variables. so the whole content in html will be echoed:

```
echo '...
      <ul class="drop_down">
    <form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">      
        <input type="submit" id="one" name="one value="one"/><div>set one</div>
    </form>
    <form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">  
        <input type="submit" id="two" name="two" value="two"><div>set two</div>
    </form>
      </ul>
     ...';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your Form

```
   <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">      
   <input type="submit" id="one" name="one" value="one"/><div>set one</div>
   </form>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">  
   <input type="submit" id="two" name="two" value="two"/><div>set two</div>
</form>
```

value Need to be sent..

---

**Edit#1:**

---

In my system this is working fine..

```
        <?php
        session_start();

        if (!isset($_SESSION['a'])){
           $var='hi';
        $_SESSION['a'] = $var;
        $var = $_SESSION['a'];
        }else{
            $var = $_SESSION['a'];
            $what = "some text";

            if (isset($_POST['one']) ){
                $var = "new input";
                    $_SESSION['a'] = $var;
                echo "one was posted";
            }
            if (isset($_POST['two']) ){
                    $var = "new input";
                    $_SESSION['a'] = $var;
                echo "two was posted";
            }   
        }
        ?>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">      
            <input type="submit" id="one" name="one"/><div>set one</div>
        </form>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">  
            <input type="submit" id="two" name="two"/><div>set two</div>
        </form>
```

---

**Edit#2**

---

Try this again...

```
        if (!isset($_SESSION['a'])){
           $var='hi';
        $_SESSION['a'] = $var;
        $var = $_SESSION['a'];
        }else{
            $var = $_SESSION['a'];
            $what = "some text";

            if (isset($_POST['one']) ){
                $var = "new input1";
                    $_SESSION['a'] = $var;
                echo "one was posted";
                print_r($_SESSION);
            }
            if (isset($_POST['two']) ){
                    $var = "new input2";
                    $_SESSION['a'] = $var;
                echo "two was posted";
                print_r($_SESSION);
            }   
        }
        ?>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">      
            <input type="submit" id="one" name="one"/><div>set one</div>
        </form>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">  
            <input type="submit" id="two" name="two"/><div>set two</div>
        </form>
```

Here `session` is printing correctly

Comment: it is existing but forget to add in the question.

Comment: this seems to be wrong also, it doesnt work. before i tried and the post was send without value. this is not necessary.

Comment: the html is set on php parser so it will echo the html.

Comment: hello and thanks for answering this question i tried edit 2 but this is not working at all.

Comment: check your php.ini for session support..:)

Answer (score 0):

This part needs clarification. What exactly are you trying to do?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['a'])){
...create the session from some variables...
$_SESSION['a'] = $var;
$var = $_SESSION['a'];
}else{
$var = $_SESSION['a'];
$what = "some text";
```

Try this:

```
    <?PHP
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['one']) )
    {
      $_SESSION['a'] = "langauage one";
      echo "one was posted";
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['two']) )
        {
            $_SESSION['a'] = "langauge two";
            echo "two was posted";
        }   
        else
            {
                if (!isset($_SESSION['a']))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['a'] = "default langauge";
                    }

            }
```

**Here is example with SELECT**

```
    <?PHP
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['language']) )
    {
      $_SESSION['a'] = $_POST['language'];
      echo "Language has ben set to ".$_POST['language'];
    }
    else
        {
            if (!isset($_SESSION['a']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['a'] = "default langauge";
                }

        }
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<select title="Please choose your Language" name="language">    
     <option value="langauage one">langauage one</option>
     <option value="langauge two">langauge two</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: i will save language-settings in the session. therefor it will read out the preferred language from the browser if given, if not it will manually set a default. that setting is saved in $var. in the next step the session is set and in case of post specific "id" to change the saved language in the session it will echo/header.

Comment: also if you are trying to set language, using a <SELECT> would work better and require less code.

Answer (score 0):

Form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">      
    <input type="submit" id="one" name="one" value='one'/><div>set one</div>
</form>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">  
    <input type="submit" id="two" name="two"value='two' /><div>set two</div>
</form>
```

Php:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['a'])){
        $var = 1;
        $_SESSION['a'] = $var;
        //$var = $_SESSION['a']; this is unnecessary 
    }else{
        $var = $_SESSION['a'];
        $what = "some text";

        if (isset($_POST['one']) ){
            $var = "one";
            $_SESSION['a'] = $var;
            echo "one was posted";
        }
        if (isset($_POST['two']) ){
            $var = "two";
            $_SESSION['a'] = $var;
            echo "two was posted";
        }   
    }

?>
```